# Use Ransack with fuzzily

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been racking my brains for a while on this issue
So I amusing ransack to search

```
@search=Sheet.ransack(params[:q])
```

Recently, I discovered this gem called fuzzily. which adds the `find_by_fuzzy_title` method to sheets. 
I could not find an integration with ransack so I was pretty much on my own
I did try some integration... Specifically by extracting ids from fuzzy search and passing them to ransack and vice versa..but these seem to have problems in ordering

**Any ransack gems that enable fuzzy searching would be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but I would imagine you could just add the find_by_fuzzy methods to the ransackable scopes on the model and ransack would pass the arguments to the fuzzy search scope. You may only be able to pass in one argument though so you might have to have a default on your scope

```
 class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   fuzzily_searchable :name
   def self.ransackable_scopes(*args)
     %w(find_by_fuzzy_name)
   end
 end
```

Then you would search like so:

```
MyModel.ransack(find_by_fuzzy_name: "mysearchterm").result
```